# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting - pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

```
def insert_data():
ch="y"
while(ch=="y" or ch=="Y"):
       i=0
       stu_roll_no=int(input("\n\nENTER THE ROLL NUMBER :"))

       q0 = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT where ROLL_NO=?"
       cur.execute(q0, (stu_roll_no,))
       a=cur.fetchall()
       for row in a:
           if(stu_roll_no == row[0]):
               print("\nTHIS ROLL NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS")
               print("\n1.UPDATE THE EXISTING RECORD\n2.INSERT NEW RECORD\nPRESS ANY KEY TO GO BACK")
               sel=input("\nENTER CHOICE : ")
               if sel=='1':
                   update_data()
                   i=1
                   ch="n"
               elif sel=='2':
                   ch="y"
                   i=1
               else:
                   admin()
                   ch="n"
                   i=1
                       
           else:
               break
       if i!=1:
           stu_name=input("ENTER STUDENT NAME :")
           father_name=input("ENTER  FATHER NAME :")
           mobile=input("ENTER THE MOBILE NO :")
           while(len(mobile)!=10):
               mobile=input("\nPLEASE ENTER 10-DIGIT MOBILE NUMBER :")
           stu_mobile_no=int(mobile)

           stu_age=int(input("ENTER STUDENT AGE :"))
           while(stu_age<=0 or stu_age>=30):
               stu_age=int(input("\nENTER CORRECT STUDENT AGE"))
           
           stu_dept=input("ENTER THE DEPARTMENT NAME :")
           stu_dept.upper()
           exam=input("ENTER EXAMINATION NAME :")
           python=int(input("ENTER MARKS IN PYTHON :"))
           rdbms=int(input("ENTER MARKS IN RDBMS :"))
           cn=int(input("ENTER MARKS IN CN :"))
           os=int(input("ENTER MARKS IN OS :"))
           ds=int(input("ENTER MARKS IN DS :"))

           cur.execute("insert into student (ROLL_NO,NAME,FATHER_NAME,MOBILE_NO,AGE,DEPARTMENT) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(stu_roll_no,stu_name,father_name,stu_mobile_no,stu_age,stu_dept))
           cur.execute("insert into result (ROLL_NO,EXAMINATION,PYTHON,RDBMS,CN,OS,DS) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(stu_roll_no,exam,python,rdbms,cn,os,ds))

           print("\n\nRECORD ENTERED SUCCESSFULLY")
           db.commit()

           ch=input("\n\nWANT TO INSERT ANOTHER RECORD ? (Y/N) : ")
```

I have problems to execute pymysql.

My computer is using windows 10, I'm
using python 3.7 on anaconda.

```
query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The issue arises with `mogrify()` on `cursor.py`. Elsewhere for this problem it says it something to do with an outdated format of % but I'm not using that.
any suggestions or fixes would be much appreciated

Comment: Please show the *entire* traceback, not just the line that throws the exception.